# Trying to print hebrew in C

Tags: c, string, visual-studio-code, unicode, hebrew

Hello i am trying to make a code that will print in hebrew and i have some questions.

1. how can i make a hebrew word into a variable and print it, what kind of a scanf/printf library do i need for that?

2.I tried something that i saw in youtube but the problem is that it prints in reverse so i dont really know how to solve it because its unicode and stuff.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl8Na.jpg)

the hebrew here is reversed.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    FILE* stream;
    if ((stream = _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT)) == NULL)
        return;
   
    wprintf(L"   \n\n\n\    שלום עולם \n\n\n");
   
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately consoles are designed for English text so they do not support Unicode very well. European languages work okay... but I think right-to-left just doesn't work.

Comment: Some terminals print Hebrew correctly, some print reversed, some don't print it at all. Your program cannot know, there is no way to query the terminal about what it does with Hebrew. If you want to print to a file, you just do it like with any other language. If you want to show Hebrew in a GUI, no problem. But with terminals you are just out of luck.

Comment: show your compile flags and definitions and the output of `chcp.com` in your terminal